# phonegap ajax call to express.js(node)

Tags: node.js, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am new to phone gap , Trying to make Ajax call to my Node.js server but it is failing .

**here is my node.js simple express code**
**Server.js file**

```
    var express = require('express')
        ,app = express()

    app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.json('{fname:"fname",lname:"lname"}')
    })    

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3015)
```

**Here is my index.html ajax call using jquery**

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://domainName:port/", //change according                    
                    success: function (data) {
                alert(success)

                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert('Error:');
                    }
                });
            })
        </script>
```

**Here is my config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.testAndroid2.firstApp2"
        versionCode = "1" 
        version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is Android only -->
    <!-- version is in major.minor.patch format --> 
    <name>PhoneGap Example App</name>

    <description>
        An example for phonegap build app which wont show up in the playstore. 
    </description>

    <author href="https://YourWebsite.com" email="yourEmail@goesHere.com">
        Name Of The Author
    </author>

    <access origin="*" />


    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <allow-intent href="*" />
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
    </platform>


</widget>
```

Ajax is failing when i build my application using phonegap build and run it on my phone , but same application is working fine in my browser of my PC (i.e there is not AJAX issue) .
Please let me know if i am missing any file in or something as i am completely new to phonegap . Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

```
There was missing Plugin (<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />)  in Config.xml file

**Config.xml file should be like :** 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.testAndroid4.firstApp4"
        versionCode = "1" 
        version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is Android only -->
    <!-- version is in major.minor.patch format --> 
    <name>PhoneGap Example App</name>

    <description>
        An example for phonegap build app which wont show up in the playstore. 
    </description>

    <author href="https://YourWebsite.com" email="yourEmail@goesHere.com">
        Name Of The Author
    </author>

    <access origin="*" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />


</widget>
```